# class has no attributed user

Tags: python, django

when i try to create a post, it will show me this error

```
Exception Type: AttributeError at /home/
Exception Value: 'HomeView' object has no attribute 'user'
```

and my view.py is

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home/home.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created')
        users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
        friend = Friend.objects.get(current_user=request.user)
        friends = friend.users.all()

        args = {
            'form': form, 'posts': posts, 'users': users, 'friends': friends
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    @login_required
    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = HomeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                post.user = request.user
                post.save()
                return redirect('home:home')
            else:
                return redirect(reverse('home:home'))
        else:
            form = HomeForm()
            args = {'form': form}
            return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "/home/zola/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     39.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/home/zola/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/home/zola/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/zola/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py"
>   in view
>     68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/zola/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py"
>   in dispatch
>     88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/zola/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py"
>   in _wrapped_view
>     22.             if test_func(request.user):

please help

I've been missing for a long time. using this language. then help me with this error

Comment: which line is causing the issue?

Comment: Can you add urls.py and full traceback?

Comment: `post.user=request.user`

Comment: Does your Post model have a user attribute?

Comment: I don't think the part of the code that has the error is included here. Please include the full code and the full traceback.

Comment: `post.user = self.request.user`

Comment: now i add tracker @AshishAcharya

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using `@login_required` decorator, use `@method_decorator(login_required)` on your post method, like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class HomeView(TemplateView):
    # ...
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def post(self, request):
        # ...
```

The reason why you're seeing an error message is because `login_required` is a *function* decorator - so it expects the `request` object to be the first argument passed to your view. Your `post` definition is a *method*, therefore `self` (`HomeView`) is the first argument that's getting passed, and this is what `login_required` tries to use as a Request instance.

`method_decorator` is used to transform every function decorator to a method decorator. [See the docs for more info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class).

Comment: Ah, brilliant! Completely missed that.