# django.contrib.auth.decorators login_required with django-rest-framework

Tags: django, reactjs, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am implementing login functions in my web app, but this error occurred.

```
File ".../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 20, in _wrapped_view
    if test_func(request.user):
AttributeError: 'QuestionListView' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Below is `views.py`, where the user is logged in using django.contrib.auth's user login function.

```
class QuestionListView(APIView):
    @login_required
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return Response({'message': 'try', 'status': 1})

class UserLoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = request.data
        user = authenticate(
            username=data['username'], password=data['password'])

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return Response({'message': 'Login successful', 'status': 1})
        else:
            return Response({'message': 'Wrong password', 'status': 0})
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', views.UserLoginView.as_view()),
    url(r'^questions/$', views.QuestionListView.as_view()),
]
```

Since I am using React JS, I redirect the page using `window.location.href = '/';` after the login button is clicked. (I am also not sure whether this is an appropriate way to redirect the page)

With reference to [class has no attributed user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232369/class-has-no-attributed-user), I tried changing `@login_required` to `@method_decorator(login_required)`. No error occurred, but instead  it triggered GET another method `"GET /accounts/login/?next=/questions/ HTTP/1.1" 200 17`

Can anyone explain how to fix this problem or to properly use @login_required?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using DRF, you should set permission classes for your `APIView`. Refactor your code like this, and it should work properly:

```py
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated


class QuestionListView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, ]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return Response({'message': 'try', 'status': 1})
```

Comment: I got `Forbidden: /questions/` instead

Comment: Then you are probably not logged in. Try logging in using your admin panel (e.g) `/admin/`